# When might the Bochner Integral not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Let $I$ be an integral on a locally compact second countable Hausdorff space $X$ and let $E$ be a Banach space. In this question all functions are taken to be measurable ($E$ and $X$ have the Borel algebras).

Let $f:X\to E$ be such that $\|f\|:X\to\Bbb R$ is an integrable function. One necessary condition on what $I(f)$ should be is:

$$\alpha(I(f))=I(\alpha(f))\quad \forall \alpha\in E^*\tag{1}$$

where $\alpha(f)$ is the function $x\mapsto \alpha(f(x))$. By $|\alpha(f(x))|≤\|\alpha\|\,\|f(x)\|$ the right-hand side always exists. The right-hand side of $(1)$ is linear in $\alpha$ and defines a continuous functional $I(f):E^*\to \Bbb C$, so an element of $E^{**}$.

> A function $f:X\to E$ with $\|f\|$ integrable is then called integrable if $I(f)\in E\subset E^{**}$. I think this is the definiton of the *Bochner-integral*. (Is that the correct term?)

My question is (roughly):

> When is it so that $I(f)\in E$?

Two examples:

Let $f\in C_C(X,E)$, then we can approximate $f$ in measure by step-functions with compact support, on which the integral is clearly defined. Since $E$ is Banach the limit of these integrals will again lie in $E$, one checks that this satisfies $(1)$.

For the other case, suppose that $E$ is the dual of some space $E^\times$ (for example $E$ is reflexive or a Hilbert space), then defining for all $\alpha'\in E^\times$:
$$\alpha'(I(f)):= I(\alpha'(f)), \quad \alpha'\in E^\times$$
we retrieve an element of $(E^\times)^*=E$. In the reflexive case $E^\times = E^*$ it is automatic that this definition satisfies $(1)$, but it is not clear to me if this holds when $E^\times$ is smaller than $E^*$.

To make my question more precise:

> 1. If $E$ has a pre-dual, is $I(f)\in E$ for $\|f\|$ integrable?
> 2. Is there another/nicer characterisation (other than is reflexive/has pre-dual) of spaces $E$ that have $I(f)\in E$ for all $\|f\|$ integrable?

Also, is there a nice example of a function $X\to E$ where $E$ has no pre-dual (for example $E=c_{0}(\Bbb N)$) so that $\|f\|$ is integrable but $I(f)\notin E$? I am having a little bit of trouble constructing such a thing on $c_{0}$, but somehow I believe it should exist.

Comment: That the nonnegative function $||f||$ is integrable is *not* sufficient for a function $f \colon X \rightarrow E$ to be integrable. You also must assume $f$ is measurable. After all, a function $f \colon [0,1] \rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$ taking random values in $\{\pm 1\}$ has $|f|$ *constant* and thus integrable on $[0,1]$, but $f$ itself is almost certainly not integrable. You can make a similar example on any $X$ with finite measure taking values in the unit sphere of $E$.

Comment: @KCd right, measurability is a different kind of problem and not one I was thinking about or am interested in. All functions in the question are taken to be measurable, I'll edit the question.

Comment: For Bochner integral (by definition) the function should be almost separably valued.  That is, there is a null set $N \subset X$ such that $f(X\setminus N)$ is separable.  There are other, more general, integrals for Banach-valued functions, such as the Pettis integral, that do not require this.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you for your comment. It is not my intention to keep piling on caveats to the question, but I'll take $X$ to be separable or even second countable in order to avoid this problem. I am aware this is a real restriction to the scenario considered, but also a restriction that is often taken.